# MySQLWorkbench Synchronise Model with command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, mysql-workbench, data-synchronization

With MySQL WorkBench, I try to find a way to execute the action : **Database -> Synchronize Model** with a **command line**.

[image]

[image]

Certain scripts of MysqlWorkbench are made in python, so, i think there is maybe a way.

Is it possible ?

The aim is to create a shell script which updates the modifications of the Diagram automatically.

I apologize in advance if my English is not quite correct.
Thanks by advance for your answers.